# Mongo-Spark connector skips objects while reading if record doesn't have fields

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm reading MongoDB collection with Mongo-Spark Connector (via Zeppelin) using Java.

```
val DataFrame = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig).toDF[Object]()
```

I'm using Object class as a view of MongoDB entity:

```
case class Object( 
    field1: Integer,
    field2: Boolean,
    ...
)
```

In MongoDB object is stored as a BSON:

```
{
  "_id": NUUID,
  "field1": 1,
  "field2": true
}
```

**Problem**: while reading data, Mongo-Spark connector skips objects, that doesn't have all the fields, mentioned in Object class.

So mongo entities like `{"id": NUUID, "field1": 2}` are not loaded to DF.

I assume, I can read all entities like BSON-objects and serialize them after reading to DF, but is there any other solution that will help not do extra-work? I.e. making class fields optional (`Option(Integer)`)

What is used:

- mongo-spark-connector_2.11
- spark-2.4.0